# Aligning text in div vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm developing an app that uses ionic elements. I'm using icons to show some stuff, and have encountered a problem. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="TITLE" ng-popstate="onPopState($state)">
    <ion-content class="background-change" scroll="true" has-bouncing="false">
        <div class="this-dir">
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
            <div class="dir-text"><strong>BLAHA</strong></div>
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
            <div class="dir-icon"><i ng-class="theIcon"></i></div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

CSS:

```
.this-dir {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.this-dir .dir-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.this-dir .dir-text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
```

Angular controller:

```
if (($scope.transaction.transaction[direction].destination_id) > ($scope.transaction.transaction[direction].origin_id)) {
    $scope.theIcon = "ion-android-arrow-forward";
} else {
    $scope.theIcon = "ion-android-arrow-back";
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, the text is currently aligned at the bottom of the icons, but I want it to be aligned at the middle. I've tried using `vertical-align:middle;` with `table-cell` but that only made all the text and the cells move to the left. I also tried using `margin-top` and `padding-top` on the inner divs but that only moved all arrows and the text simultaneously.

Comment: You don’t need to make the elements table-cells, to apply vertical-align to them – since they are inline-blocks, they are affected by it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to .dir-icon and .dir-text, and add a line-height to .dir-text equal to the height of .dir-icon.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/199n5d6t/ (added a width, height, and and background color to the icons for visibility, you can ignore this)

Comment: It worked very well, although I needed to add `line-height` on `.dir-icon` also which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add class for the `<strong>` element and use the following CSS:

```
strong.ClassName {
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a line-height for the text equal to the height of the icons and then vertical align the text, as Leon said.